# Turn off uiswitch from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I'm using LocalNotifications in my `AppDelegate.m`
If the user has the app open, the notification comes in the form of an alert.
The `AppDelegate.m` receives the `clickedButtonAtIndex` event. Regardless of the current view the user sees, the alert shows and everything works fine so far.

However, when receiving the event, I'd like to change the state of a UISwitch that exists on a UIVIewController.

EDIT: ADDED MORE CODE
My App is set up this way:

AppDelegate.m has this code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    // Called from the local notification above when the View button is clicked and the app reopens
    //called when app is open vs in background
    NSLog(@"got notification");
    UIApplicationState state=[application applicationState];
    if(state==UIApplicationStateActive){
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notice"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Sleep"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Turn Off", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"clicked button");
    if(buttonIndex==1){
        SettingsPage *setPage = [[SettingsPage alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [setPage clickedAlert];
    }
}
```

SettingsPage.m has this code:

```
@interface SettingsPage()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *alarmSwitch;
@end

@implementation SettingsPage

-(IBAction)setAlarm{
  //clear all notifications before setting a new one
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

  //set a new LocalNotification
  UILocalNotification *localNotification=localNotification =[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  if(localNotification!=nil){
      localNotification.fireDate=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];  //seconds
      localNotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
      localNotification.alertBody=@"Reminder!";
      localNotification.hasAction=YES; //fires didreceive event, opens app
      localNotification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];           }
}
-(void)clickedAlert{
    NSLog(@"clicked alert");
    [self.alarmSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

This has the desired effect of setting the "alarmSwitch" to "Off" (and thus canceling further notices), but the switch itself still shows in the view as "On" (green).

How can I flip the actual switch on the SettingsPage via code from my AppDelegate.m so that it behaves the same as if the user did it (i.e. changes it's visual and executes the connected method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CrimsonChris mentioned, you seem to be making a new instance of SettingsPage every time, thus you're not seeing the change you want.

You could fire off an NSNotification,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ClickedButtonAtIndex1" object:nil];
```

..and listen to it in your UIViewController.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleIndex1Clicked) name:@"ClickedButtonAtIndex1" object:nil];
```

with your UIViewController doing what it needs to in the selector method:

```
-(void)handleIndex1Clicked
{
    [self.setPage.alarmSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

PS.  I'd suggest having extern const NSStrings holding your observer names.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How does an NSNotificationCenter compare to UILocalNotification? Will it work when the app is in the background like UILocalNotification?

Comment: NSNotifcations are native to your app and are not displayed to the user. They are not run when the app is in the background, only when it is alive.  NSNotifications are used when when one class witnesses a certain event that another class may be interested in knowing about.

Comment: OK - then I can't use NSNotifications - my app sets up reminders to show while it's in the background...if it's in the foreground it uses alerts when the local notification occurs.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Would this setting be changed only if the user taps on the LocalNotification?  If so, you can handle it in the didFinishLaunching (if the app was killed), or didReceiveLocalNotification (if the was just in the background).. which looks like what you are doing.  The issue is with "SettingsPage *setPage", you're making a brand new instance of the SettingsPage object, you need to grab the one that already exists.

Comment: Sorry to not be much help.  Perhaps you could save the state when the LocalNotification is handled, and when you display the Settings page, set the setting appropriately.

Comment: I revisited your suggestion and with a little more understanding of NSNotifications on my part - it works! I can not only execute method(s) I can show the switch changing positions - Sorry I was so dense earlier - THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting a new `SettingsPage` and then setting its `alarmSwitch` to "Off". What you probably want is to get the existing `SettingsPage` instead of making a new one with alloc init.

Comment: Seems logical - how do I get a reference to the existing SettingsPage?

Comment: You could use a @property. You shouldn't need to "get" a reference to the your existing `SettingsPage`. You should "keep" a reference to it somewhere, probably your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Why can't the `SettingsPage` be the thing that handles `clickedButtonAtIndex`?

Comment: The AppDelegate.m creates the Alert so the SettingsPage never sees it. I believe I need to set the Alert Delegate to the SettingsPage instead of 'self' but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Just keep a reference to your `SettingsPage` in the `AppDelegate`. Where is your `SettingsPage` coming from? If you show us more code it might help us figure out exactly what is confusing you.

Comment: Can you show an example of how to keep a reference to the SettingsPage in the AppDelgate.m ?

Comment: @wayneh How are you presenting your `SettingsPage`?

Comment: From a UITableViewController / toolbar. Storyboard flow is: NavController->TableViewController w/toolbar button -> SettingsPage. See the code I just posted too.

Comment: You didn't mention storyboards in your question. I'll have to do some research on how track existing view controllers in storyboards. Storyboarded apps tend to be structured very differently.

Comment: Are you creating your `SettingsPage` in code with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` or are you letting the Storyboard do that for you?